# What kind of screw should I use to mount an electrical box inside a cabinet?

Tags: electrical

What type and size of screw should I use to mount a 4”x4” metal electrical box to the back of the under the sink cabinet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For box mounting I use 2 #8 pan/ washer head screws. All the ones I have seen are Phillips or square drive #2, but there may be straight. Inspectors like the square head #2 because usually only electricians use these so it can help you pass inspection. At least 3/4” but 1” is the max I normally buy because the next size is usually 1.5” and that’s too long, especially if no drywall (don’t want to drive a screw through a cable).

Comment: My answer would've been "almost anything". What criteria are you trying to meet with these specific suggestions? What are inspectors looking for?

Comment: Not sure of your issue I stated,  inspectors like the washer head because they won’t damage a plastic box (box type not listed).  Also when they see a square drive the think electrician and may not be as big of a jerk to a home owner. I was hired to fix an entire house that the owner wired he used bugle head screws and cracked some of the boxes the inspector flagged all of them. I pulled the screws and installed washer head square drives. Several of his wires coming out of the boxes were 5.99” not kidding I pulled the slack for 6”. Owner told me he inspected 1 box saw square drive and signed.

Comment: To be fair, you didn't mention box damage in your answer. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Driving that screw is a pretty simple task and you could make due with anything close to suitable - something in the size 8-10 range, at least 1/2" long but not so long it goes through the cabinetry into who knows what, hopefully threads coarse enough to hold well  in manufactured wood-like substrates.  Ideally a washer head but a pan head will do, a tapered flat head won't sit right and will leave a little sharp bit exposed.

Working inside a box, inside a cabinet, half lying on the floor, is pretty awkward.  A slotted screw will be a real pain, a phillips screw will be better but could still be difficult.  A screw that stays on the driver well will help a lot.  You could use a hex-washer head screw, and a nutdriver with a strong magnet.  My preference is a square drive screw, they stay on very well for me.  Of course, using a power tool rather than a hand driver will also make things easier.